# Why is :w command so slow for a relatively small file?

Tags: vimrc, save

I have a file with 30000 lines (3MB), when I use `:w` vim editor hangs for several seconds, but when I use pure vim/vi it takes only a moment to save the changes.

Why do I get this effect? What could be causing this lag?

**Update:** Changed original question *What is the difference between :w and :up?* to *Why :w command is so slow for relatively small file?*

Comment: Is the buffer modified in both cases?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt You are right! I didn't make any changes when used ```:up``` command. ```:up``` also hangs for several seconds. But the question remains, which functionality creates the lag?

Comment: Is this reproducable when starting vim like vim -u NONE -N file.log or using `:noa :w`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt No, the lag problem is not reprocessable when using ```vim -u NONE -N file.log``` command to open the file, it takes only a moment to save the changes. And ```:nao``` command is not found.

Comment: @niekas the command should be `:noa` or `:noautocmd` instead of _:nao_

Comment: use **:noa**. In any case, you might want to debug this further see https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5

Comment: To find out which 'write' autocmds are added by your vimrc, directly or through plugins, you could run `:verbose autocmd {event}` for each write event listed at `:help autocommand-events`. Then do the same after starting Vim with `-u NONE` and compare the result. If the problem is caused by a write autocmd, this should give you a hint where to look.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a problem with the asker's .vimrc and that .vimrc is not provided in the question.

Comment: Also possible: creating the undo file may take some time, if enabled in the vimrc. Probably not several seconds, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just comment, but not enough reputation.

Looking at `:help up` it says "Like `:write`, but only write when the buffer has been modified."

Comment: Yes, I looked it up before, but this definition does not explain the performance difference of these two commands.

Comment: I guess its caused by one of commands in my .vimrc, since not all the file is created by me, I don't know what kind of command to look for. And the problem persists only with big files. Maybe its caused by file backing up (undofile, swap)?

Comment: @niekas It does explain the difference if your performance problem is related to writing the buffer to file (which seems likely). When the buffer is not modified, `:update` will not write to file, _ergo_ no problem. In that case, this answers your original question correctly. Nick's answer may be off because _it answers your question, but doesn't solve your problem_. In that case, you might consider accepting this answer and asking your new question in a, well, new question.